# Java-Min and max values of an array using Collections

Tags: java

Im trying to get the max and min values from one dimesional array as

```
double[] source = {1.2,1.3,1.9,0.9,0.10};
double[][] maxar = new double[10][ 5];
double x=Collections.max(source);
double y=Collections.min(source);
```

the compiler run-time errors are :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: The method max(Collection<? extends T>) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (double[])


The method min(Collection<? extends T>) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (double[])
```

Any help will be highly appreciated ?

Comment: The error message says it all. Collections.min() returns the minimum element of a Collection. Not the minimum element of an array of primitive doubles: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#min%28java.util.Collection%29. What is your question?

Comment: @JBNizet My guess? OP doesn't realise that autoboxing doesn't extend to arrays

Comment: I need to get the max and min values for this array using a Collections. I know the Collections doesn't work with an array, but how cal i make it work with such type of array?  JB Nizet

Answer (score 0):

You can use the apache commons lang package and solve the same.

```
        Double[] doubleArray = ArrayUtils.toObject(source);
        List<Double> list = Arrays.asList(doubleArray);

        double x=Collections.max(list);
        double y=Collections.min(list);

        System.out.println(x);
        System.out.println(y);
```

Comment: Amz: can you please refer to the link to download the apache commons lang package. I found many libraries in google

Comment: Download 2.6 jar from the below location and add the same to the build path of your project.http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi

Comment: Thank Amz: I have import the commons-lang-2.6-src and commons-collections4-4.0-bin as zip and then unzip and Build path for them but i still have an error as redline under     ArrayUtils.toObject(source); in addition , i make import org.apache.commons.lang.ArrayUtils;
please help in this issue

Comment: Download commons-lang-2.6-bin.zip from the path http://mirror.nexcess.net/apache//commons/lang/binaries/commons-lang-2.6-bin.zip.    Extracting the zip you will find a jar file name as commons-lang-2.6.jar.This jar you put in the build path of the project.